# Why is the first section of my page showing partially when the screen is around 800px?

Tags: html, css

It looks fine below 700px and above approximately 10000px.
The first section of the page (under the class 'firstPage') only shows up partially between those two sizes. The rest of the page looks fine in all sizes.
This is all HTML and CSS, no JavaScript

Here's some of the Code for the first section:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
  
}

/* First page */
.firstPage {
  background-color: #1c1a19;
  background-image: url('Group.png');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% 170%;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.headline {
  margin: 0 24px 0 24px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.secondPage {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  width: 100%;
}

.secondItem {
  background-image: url('secondBG.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  width: 87.2%;
}

.bigText {
  font-family: Crete-Round, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 44px;
  color: white;
}

.smallText {
  font-family: Inter, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: white;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.mainText {
  color: black;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.socials {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
/* First page */
  .container {
    background: #3E3C3C;
    margin:0;
    padding: 26px 154px;
  }
  .firstPage {
    background-image: url('./Desktop/Illustration-header.png');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:100% 45%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
<!-- Beginning of first page -->
    <section class="firstPage">
    <header class="container">
       <a href="#" class="name">John Doe</a>
        <nav class="hamburger"> 
            <img src="icons/Union.png" alt="Hamburger menu icon">
        </nav>
    </header>
<section class="desktopRow">
<section class="headline">
    <h1 class="title">Hey There.
        I'm Alex</h1>
    <h3 class="subtitle">I'm a Software Developer</h3>
    <p class="description">I can help you build a product, feature or website Look through some of my work and experience! If you like what you see and have a project you need coded, 
        don't hestiate to contact me.</p>
    </section>
<ul class="icons">
    <li><a href="https://github.com/Daf98"><img src="./icons/Github.png" alt="Github icon"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://linkedin.com/in/dafne-azzolina/"><img src="./icons/Linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn icon"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://angel.co/"><img src="./icons/Angelist.png" alt="AngelList icon"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/dafne_azzolina"><img src="./icons/Twitter.png" alt="Twitter icon"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://medium.com/"><img src="./icons/Medium.png" alt="Medium icon"></a></li>
</ul>
</section>
</section>
<!-- Beginning of second page -->
<section class="secondPage">
<section class="works">
    <div class="whitePart">
    <h2 class="workTitle">My recent works</h2>
    <img src="css/Border.png" alt="Border" class="border"></div>
<section class="preCard">  
    <div class="card1">
       <img class="yoga" src="css/Works/Preview.png" alt="Preview"></div>
   <div class="overflow">
       <h2 class="bigText mainText">Multi-Post Stories</h2>
       <p class="smallText mainText">A daily selection of privately personalized reads; no accounts or sign-ups required. has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a standard dummy text.</p>
        <ul class="socials">
            <li class="boxes specialItem">CSS</li>
            <li class="boxes specialItem">HTML</li>
            <li class="boxes specialItem">Bootstrap</li>
            <li class="boxes specialItem">Ruby</li>
        </ul>
   <button type="button" class="specialButton">See Project</button>
    </div>
</section>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Here's what it looks like
[image: Here's what it looks like]

Comment: you have some padding on 768px and up on the `.headline`. Just look in the styles inspector ... `styles.css` line 512

Comment: It looks the same if I remove the padding

Comment: ALWAYS MORE... *above approximately 10000px* are you planing to shoot your website in a cinema ?

Answer (score 0):

To confirm if it works you should upload your image.

But I suspect the fact that the image is higher than larger between 768px and **1000px** so it does not stretch. Try to add a `background-size: cover;` to `.firstPage`

### Demo

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  background-color: white;
  
}

/* First page */
.firstPage {
  background-color: #1c1a19;
  /*background-image: url('Group.png');*/
  background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/600x800/87b5f5/dd00ff');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: 100% 170%;
  background-size: cover; /************ADDED**********/
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 100%;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: whitesmoke;
}

ul {
  list-style: none;
}

.headline {
  margin: 0 24px 0 24px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
}

.secondPage {
  background: #e5e5e5;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr;
  width: 100%;
}

.secondItem {
  background-image: url('secondBG.png');
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 4px;
  padding: 20px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
  width: 87.2%;
}

.bigText {
  font-family: Crete-Round, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 32px;
  line-height: 44px;
  color: white;
}

.smallText {
  font-family: Inter, sans-serif;
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 24px;
  color: white;
  padding-right: 10px;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.mainText {
  color: black;
  padding-left: 10px;
}

.socials {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 10px;
}
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {
/* First page */
  .container {
    background: #3E3C3C;
    margin:0;
    padding: 26px 154px;
  }
  .firstPage {
    /*background-image: url('./Desktop/Illustration-header.png');*/
    background-image: url('https://dummyimage.com/600x800/87b5f5/dd00ff');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position:100% 45%;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
<!-- Beginning of first page -->
    <section class="firstPage">
    <header class="container">
       <a href="#" class="name">John Doe</a>
        <nav class="hamburger"> 
            <img src="icons/Union.png" alt="Hamburger menu icon">
        </nav>
    </header>
<section class="desktopRow">
<section class="headline">
    <h1 class="title">Hey There.
        I'm Alex</h1>
    <h3 class="subtitle">I'm a Software Developer</h3>
    <p class="description">I can help you build a product, feature or website Look through some of my work and experience! If you like what you see and have a project you need coded, 
        don't hestiate to contact me.</p>
    </section>
<ul class="icons">
    <li><a href="https://github.com/Daf98"><img src="./icons/Github.png" alt="Github icon"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://linkedin.com/in/dafne-azzolina/"><img src="./icons/Linkedin.png" alt="LinkedIn icon"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://angel.co/"><img src="./icons/Angelist.png" alt="AngelList icon"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://twitter.com/dafne_azzolina"><img src="./icons/Twitter.png" alt="Twitter icon"></a></li>
    <li><a href="https://medium.com/"><img src="./icons/Medium.png" alt="Medium icon"></a></li>
</ul>
</section>
</section>
<!-- Beginning of second page -->
<section class="secondPage">
<section class="works">
    <div class="whitePart">
    <h2 class="workTitle">My recent works</h2>
    <img src="css/Border.png" alt="Border" class="border"></div>
<section class="preCard">  
    <div class="card1">
       <img class="yoga" src="css/Works/Preview.png" alt="Preview"></div>
   <div class="overflow">
       <h2 class="bigText mainText">Multi-Post Stories</h2>
       <p class="smallText mainText">A daily selection of privately personalized reads; no accounts or sign-ups required. has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a standard dummy text.</p>
        <ul class="socials">
            <li class="boxes specialItem">CSS</li>
            <li class="boxes specialItem">HTML</li>
            <li class="boxes specialItem">Bootstrap</li>
            <li class="boxes specialItem">Ruby</li>
        </ul>
   <button type="button" class="specialButton">See Project</button>
    </div>
</section>
</section>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It did not work https://imgur.com/a/Veu0Zk9

Comment: You still need to provide image to get more help